Adobe digital editions: connection error with xebook
I cannot open books from xebook, and the popup text reads Connection Error Detected: Digital Editions could not connect to the fulfillment server
Books from other servers always work fine.
I've deleted and resinstalled it, changing my ID too.
I'm on Windows 7, ADE 4.5
